# How to achieve a feature similar to Post Offline feature of facebook in a iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Hi I'm trying to achieve a feature similar to Facebook's Post Offline feature in my application. What I need to know is can we run a background service in iOS which will cache all the data of the the application when the app is offline (i.e network is unavailable ) and will post the data to the server when the network is available. So it would be really helpful if someone can give some suggestions how this can be achieved. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a events queue using a database table, then have a background thread to dequeue the table and send the data.

You can create the background worker thread with GCD:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  while(true) {
    // check reachability
    // dequeue and send data
  }
});
```

The worker thread could check the network availability using some reachability API (see https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html and https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)